# The different of describe(it()) and describe(test())

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have seen many examples of testing in ReactJS use it()

Example:

```
describe('General behaviour', () => {
  it('should call toggle() when clicked', () => {
    // expect something 
});
```

and I see the example of jest use test()

Example:

```
describe('matching cities to foods', () => {
  test('Vienna <3 sausage', () => {
    expect(isValidCityFoodPair('Vienna', 'Wiener Schnitzel')).toBe(true);
});
```

[see more jest for react example in this link](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-react.html).

What are the differrent of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`it` is just [`test` aliased.](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/api.html#testname-fn-timeout)

People coming from Jasmine and other testing frameworks use `it.